# Deriving the potential function for a gradient field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to write out the general formula for finding the potential function from a gradient field; but I'm encountering an issue.

My current working is:

$$Let\space F = f(x,y,z)$$

$$\nabla\vec{F} = <\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}>$$

$$F=\int_{}\frac{\partial{f}}{{\partial{x}}}dx = f(x,y,z) +c(y,z)$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(f(x,y,z) +c(y,z)) =\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$

$$ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{c}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$

$$ \frac{\partial{c}}{\partial{y}} = 0 $$

I'm presuming I'm using bad notation that is obscuring my error and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to distinguish the components $F_x, F_y, F_z$ of the vector field $F$ from the components $\partial_x f, \partial_y f, \partial_z f$ of the gradient of $f$. You are attempting to come up with a formula that shows they are equal, so you can't assume they're the same from the start.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Since I have defined F = f(x,y,z), aren't the partials equivalent? Also, thanks for responding

Comment: Your problem solution does not correspond to problem statement. Let $F=f(x,y,z)$, and let we know, that $\nabla F=<g_x, g_y, g_z>$, that is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=g_x(x,y,z)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=g_y(x,y,z)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=g_z(x,y,z)$, then $f(x,y,z)=\int g_x(x,y,z)\, dx+h(y,z)$. Taking derivative by $y$: $g_y(x,y,z)=\int \frac{\partial g_x}{\partial y}\, dx+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$.

Comment: This line does not follow from previous: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(f(x,y,z) +c(y,z)) =\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but to get any antiderivative of an integrable vector field you only need to compute any of it integrals, that is, if $\mathbf{F}$ is an integrable vector field then for some fixed but arbitrary $\mathbf{h}_0\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and arbitrary constant $C\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that

$$
V(\mathbf{h}):=C+\int_{\mathbf{h_0}}^{\mathbf{h}} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}
$$

defines a potential $V$ for $\mathbf{F}$, where the integral is assumed over any regular path $\varphi_{\mathbf{h}} :[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\varphi_{\mathbf{h}} (a)=\mathbf{h_0}$ and $\varphi _{\mathbf{h}}(b)=\mathbf{h}$. There $d\mathbf{r}=(dx,dy,dz)=\mathbf{i}dx+\mathbf{j}dy+\mathbf{k}dz$ so $\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=F_1dx+F_2dy+F_3dz$ for $\mathbf{F}=(F_1,F_2,F_3)=\mathbf{i}F_1+\mathbf{j}F_2+\mathbf{k}F_3$.

There its tacitly assumed that $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)=\mathbf{i}x+\mathbf{j}y+\mathbf{k}z$ and that $\mathbf{F}$ is a function in $\mathbf{r}$, that is, the notation $\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ is a shorthand for $F_1(x,y,z)dx+F_2(x,y,z)dy+F_3(x,y,z)dz$, where the points $(x,y,z)$ belong to the image of $\varphi _{\mathbf{h}}$.

Then, in it concrete form for some chosen $\varphi _{\mathbf{h}}$, you have that

$$
\int_{\mathbf{h_0}}^{\mathbf{h}} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_{a}^b (\mathbf{F}\circ \varphi _{\mathbf{h}})(t)\cdot \dot \varphi _{\mathbf{h}}(t)\,d t=\int_{a}^b \sum_{k=1}^3 (F_k\circ \varphi _{\mathbf{h}})(t)\dot \varphi _{k,\mathbf{h}}(t)\,d t
$$

for $\varphi _{\mathbf{h}}=(\varphi _{1,\mathbf{h}},\varphi _{2,\mathbf{h}},\varphi _{3,\mathbf{h}})=\mathbf{i}\varphi _{1,\mathbf{h}}+\mathbf{j}\varphi _{2,\mathbf{h}}+\mathbf{k}\varphi _{3,\mathbf{h}}$.